# Google Play In-App Purchases - querySkuDetailsAsync doesn't return status (active/inactive)

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I'm trying to display all the possible options a user can buy, but I either don't want to list inactive ones, or want to grey/ghost them out, and maybe have coming soon on them.

However the call `billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync()` provides a list of `SkuDetail` and that doesn't have the status in it.

It's possible that the originalJson has it, but I haven't checked that, though the documentation doesn't appear to say that it would.

EDIT: (I've just checked and originalJson doesn't have it either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't available in the [SkuDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails.html) response payload from the query (as you also confirmed in the original Json).

Looking into the Issue Tracker for the Play Billing Library, someone else has brought this up to the team :: [Add getState (state = active / inactive) to SkuDetails](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69751301), in which its still active so it may be available in the future.

For now, you'll have to track which ones are inactive in the app and filter the response when its received.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. Even after two years still SKU query does not include the status. As of now, query still returns all items including inactive in-app items, only code change in application can restrict showing inactive items to the end app users.